# Create script for all the indexes already existing

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I get the create script for all the `indexes` already existing in the db. I am checking from oracle sql developer.

Comment: Are you looking an answer for Oracle? then, why did you tagged as DB2? those are different RDBS.

Comment: I have connected to `DB2` through `Oracle Sql Developer` client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `db2look` command

```
db2look -d <DB NAme> -u walid -e -m -o db2look.sql
```

Comment: Can't I generate that from `Oracle-Sql-Developer` ?

Comment: This statement will only work if the userID `walid` created the objects you're interested in.  You may want to investigate the `-z` option for `db2look`.